# KJUR.jws.JWS does not support unencoded payload while creating jws signature

Tags: node.js, json-web-signature

When i am trying b64:false in header it seems to have no effect. Is this not supported yet in KJUR.jws.JWS ? And can someone point me in direction of a good node js library for jws.

Answer (score 0):

"jose" is a good library for this. It handles unencoded payload by default if you give b64:false in protected headers.